# Perl: Read path from command line

Tags: perl

I'm newbie in perl and I got some problem with one thing.

I have code:

```
$original_file = "y:\\Users\\XXX\\perlScript\\test1.xml";
$new_file = "y:\\Users\\XXX\\perlScript\\summary_test1.xml";
copy($original_file, $new_file) or die "File cannot be copied";
```

I need read path from cmd command line (I use batch file).
For Example:

```
>summary.bat c>\path\file_name.xml
```

After copy I'd like create `summary_file_name.xml` to same folder

Thanks

Comment: Did you really type in `c>\path\file_name.xml` or did you mean to type a colon instead?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how a Perl program gets its command line arguments? You'll find them in the `@ARGV` array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `File::Basename`. This is a standard library in Perl, at least as early as 5.14, so you do not need to install anything new.

```
use File::Basename;
my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($original_file);
my $new_file = $directories . "/summary.xml";
```

For more information, see the [Perl Docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html).